# How to increase the height of highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using HighCharts for displaying some statistical data but i have a problem that when values of x axis increases, it cuts down the values. I am attaching screenshot.

[image]

Comment: do you have some jsfiddle code to share?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add marginBottom:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 70 /* HERE */
            },
            title: {
                text: '@Model.Title',
                x: -20 
            }
```

Comment: any way to add +20px to the margin?  i.e. read what the margin is already and add 20px

Answer (score 12):

There's an API method to set the size of the chart, found on the chart object and called setSize. `chart.setSize(width, height)` see this [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShGZk/8) and the [reference](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-object).

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that method... thanks for saving me some time.

Comment: UPDATED setSize() REFERENCE: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-setsize-button/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
var height = //get containers original height

var new_height = height + (data.length * 10);

$("#highcharts-0").css("{height:"+new_height+"}");
```